# How to perform UPSERT with duplicate records captured in different file in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have below requirement-

- Source: Oracle
- Target: SQL server
- **Load type**: UPSERT
- **Primary key on target column**: (id+deptid+ctid)
- **Target table columns**

  - Name
  - ID
  - deptID
  - CtID
  - Place
  - quant
  - total_buy

I have to load the data into table and perform update else insert. I also need to perform below for error reporting:

- On Key violation, please skip that record and continue on loading the records. The skipped records  save it in File (ct_err_.txt and save it on archive directory for 30 days. Data in error file is (id, deptid, ctid).

I have tried:

```
SQ -flow1 -> aggregation -> err file
   -flow2 -> sorter-lookup on target -> router-update else insert.
```

But it i not working properly.

Can you please help me here with the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the first flow. All you need is the flow2 and on your `Target` in `Session -> Mapping tab` set the `Reject file directory` and `Reject filename` properties accordingly.

Informatica automatically does fulfill your requirement by redirecting rejected rows to a file of your choice. You may need to adjust the `Stop on errors` property in `Config Object` tab of the session.

Comment: Agree with Maceiejg, but I am not sure if its a good idea to use 'stop on error' property. I like how OP used a logic to catch them and store them as error rows in a file/table.